# ORA-27492: unable to run job "APEX_040200.ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE": scheduler unavailable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

My Oracle APEX applications have stopped sending email from the mail queue. After doing a bit of troubleshooting, I have narrowed the issue down to the scheduled job APEX_040200.ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE. The procedure that is called by this job works fine when I run in manually, as does  the "Force Send" option in the Internal workspace. However, this scheduled job hasn't successfully run in over a month now. I tried dropping the job entirely and rebuilding it using the DDL from the same job in my testing environment, but that didn't seem to work.

I tried testing the rebuilt job by clicking on the "Find My Workspace" link prior to logging into my workspace because it is an easy way to generate a test email in APEX. As soon as I clicked on the link, an error page loaded with the following message: ORA-27492:

> unable to run job "APEX_040200.ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE": scheduler
>   unavailable

From the online research I've done, most users have resolved this problem with some variation of the command

> Alter system set job_queue_processes=1000;

That didn't work for me. I'm wondering if it might be a permissions issue of some sort. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's a whole lot of different reasons why it might be failing - check the list here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/648581

Answer (score 0):

```
select      attribute_name,
            value
from        dba_scheduler_global_attribute
where       attribute_name = 'SCHEDULER_DISABLED';

ATTRIBUTE_NAME     VALUE 
------------------ ----- 
SCHEDULER_DISABLED TRUE 

-- Attribute vanishes when set to false (run as sysdba)
dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute ( 'SCHEDULER_DISABLED', 'FALSE' );
```